# Replace all names in a table with ID from second table

Tags: sql

I have a Table with several columns that have a full name in. I need to change the Names in each with the User ID I have in a Second Table.

Table 1.

| Opener | Closer | Manager |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Ed Woods | Rich Bell | Ed Woods |
| James Smith | James Smith | James Smith |
| Rich Bell | Rich Bell | James Smith |

Users

| ID | Full Name_1 |
| --- | --- |
| 917863 | Rich Bell |
| 45276345 | James Smith |
| 687323 | Ed Woods |

I'm using Zoho Analytics for this and I'm not 100% up on SQL. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select uo.id as Opener,
       uc.id as Closer,
       um.id as Manager
from table1 t1
left join users uo on uo.Name_1 = t1.opener
left join users uc on uc.Name_1 = t1.closer
left join users um on um.Name_1 = t1.manager
```

Comment: I'm getting the following error

Whenever a table alias is defined, kindly use table alias name before the respective columns used in SELECT query

Comment: @RichardLee . . . That is an odd error on this statement, because the column names are qualified.

Comment: @RichardLee: My guess is that your real statement contains more columns in the SELECT or WHERE 
clause, right?